# Dynamically Creating a popup window without jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, code-behind

I need to create a popup window that shows an error stored in a string variable from the code behind of an ASP site without using Jquery or Ajax.  How can I make this work?  I believe it has to do with ScriptManager but I am unsure...

Comment: You might want to also try this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220746/a-modal-popup-with-out-using-ajax-update-panel-jquery-or-javascript-surprisin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is writing a function that has an error message returned from sql as an out statement, and then using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript instead of the ScriptManager.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "failed", string.Format("alert({0});", AntiXss.JavaScriptEncode(error)), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RegisterStartupScript

```
string errorMessageString = "Error Here";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "UniqeKey", string.format("alert('{0}');", errorMessageString), true);
```

Comment: I am inside a static function, so I can't use "this" sadly

Answer (score 0):

You can use PopUpControl in an ASP.net AJAX extender. Below should help

> ```
> <ajaxToolkit:PopupControlExtender ID="PopEx" runat="server"  
> TargetControlID="DateTextBox"  
> PopupControlID="Panel1"  
> Position="Bottom" />
> ```